# MSSQL find most recent measurement of most recent visit where person seen within the last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, nested

The only generic example I can think of is with people seeing a doctor keeps trying to lower the patient's temperature so I'd want to see the lowest reading.

patients.patient_ID, patients.doc_ID

visits.visit_ID, visits.patient_ID, visits.doc_ID, visits.datetime

vitals.vitals_ID, vitals.visit_ID, vitals.patient_ID, vitals.temp, vitals.datetime

doctor.doc_ID, doctor.name

```
select patients.patient_ID, last_visit.temp, last_visit.maxdate  
from patients  
inner join doctor on patients.doc_ID = doctor.doc_ID  
inner join (  
    select visits.patient_ID, last_vitals.temp, max(visits.datetime) as maxdate  
    from visits  
    inner join (  
        select vitals.visit_ID, vitals.temp, max(vitals.datetime) as maxvitals
        from vitals
        group by vitals.visit_ID, vitals.temp
        )  as last_vitals on visits.visit_ID = last_vitals.visit_ID
    group by visits.patient_ID, visits.datetime  
    having visits.datetime >= DATEADD(mm, -12, GETDATE())  
    ) as last_visit on patient.patient_ID = last_visit.patient_ID  

where doctor.name = 'Dr. Jones'
```

My attempts end up returning too many results with any attempt I make.  I don't know if I'm supposed to nest the joins to get the most recent temperature for the most recent visit?  And if so, do I join to the visits first and then vitals or vice versa?  Or am I approaching this incorrectly altogether?

Any fresh ideas are truly appreciated.

Comment: Question, your data tables make it look as if a person has a primary doctor, but their visit might be performed by a different doctor, but furthermore vitals taken at a visit might be on a different patient. Especially the last condition doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this problem differently altogether.  You have 3 problems to solve.

1. what is the top visit per person per doctor in last 12 months
2. what is the most recent measurement per visit
3. only show results for Dr. Jones as primary care physician

The first two can be solved with a view or CTE and then joined against.  I recommend separate views so you can evolve your application logic (if the definition of *mostrecent whatever* changes, you update that view).  Here is a CTE example though to see it all in one place:

**old:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3552e/8

**new based on per patient per doctor:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/660be/3

```
with mostrecent_visits_per_patient_per_doctor as (
  select a.patientid,b.doctorid,max(b.visitdate) visitdate
    from patients a
    join visits b on a.patientid = b.patientid
   where b.visitdate >= dateadd(mm,-12,getdate())
   group by a.patientid,b.doctorid
), mostrecent_vitals_per_visit as (
  select a.visitid visitid,max(b.vitalsdate) topvitalsdate
    from visits a
    join vitals b on a.visitid = b.visitid
   group by a.visitid
)

select a.patientid
      ,b.visitid
      ,b.visitdate
      ,p_docs.docname primary_physician
      ,v_docs.docname attending_physician
      ,c.temp
      ,c.vitalsdate
  from patients a
  join visits b on a.patientid = b.patientid
  join vitals c on b.visitid = c.visitid
  join doctors p_docs on a.doctorid = p_docs.doctorid
  join doctors v_docs on b.doctorid = v_docs.doctorid
  join mostrecent_visits_per_patient_per_doctor x
        on a.patientid = x.patientid
       and b.doctorid = x.doctorid
       and b.visitdate = x.visitdate
  join mostrecent_vitals_per_visit z
        on c.visitid = z.visitid
       and c.vitalsdate = z.topvitalsdate
 --where p_docs.docname = 'Dr. Jones'
```

Comment: A patient can be seen by other doctors but one is assigned as the patients primary doctor.

Comment: Then do you want the most recent visit per patient or per patient per doctor?  This is where the fact that the definition of each case being laid out in a CTE or view is advantageous... individually, they are simple queries and easy to maintain.

Comment: I should've put these assumptions in:
A patient has 1 primarycare provider, yet potentially others can be the rendering provider on a visit
All primary keys are random numbers- so max(b.visitid) wouldn't work.  but max(visits.datetime) would


So I'd want to find all of Dr. Henry's patients where (Henry = patients.doc_id) and the patients' most recent temperature recording on a visit where Dr. Henry is the rendering provider (Henry = visits.doc_id)

Comment: That last update is about all I can justify throwing at this particular issue.  You should see the point of my approach however... if you like it use it.  Define each concept as a view, then join against it to limit your basic join to what you want.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks.  I really appreciate the help.  I'd never heard of Common Table Expressions.  I'm reading up on them to make sure I can understand the concept and then look back at your solution.

Comment: They are awesome... basically think View.  That's truly all they are, except they are declared within the context of a single query instead of taking up space in your database.  So if you don't expect to reuse the logic, use a CTE.  If you do, then push the CTE's out to views.  Think of them as anonymous views (like anonymous methods in C# if that helps).  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, `row_number()` seems like it should be part of the solution.  This enumerates rows (say for a patient) and orders them (say by the vital timestamp) and assigns a sequence number.  You want to order them in reverse and then choose the first one.

The structure of the query looks like:

```
select t.*
from (select *,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by patient_id order by vitals.datetime desc) as seqnum
      from patients p join
           doctor d
           on p.doc_ID = d.doc_ID join
           visits vis
           on vis.patient_id = p.patient_id join
           vitals v
           on vit.visit_id = vis.visit_id
      where doctor.name = 'Dr. Jones'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I find it hard to follow your logic . . . this uses the vitals timestamp for the ordering.  Do you want that or the visit time stamp, for instance?

Comment: I'll see if I can rephrase it: 
A patient can have multiple visits and a visit can have multiple temperature recordings.
I'd want the most recent visit timestamp and most recent temperature recording on that visit